# A ball around of a generic point has a positive ergodic measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $T:X \to X$ be a continuous function on the compact metric space $X$. We say that $\mu$ is $T-$ invarint if $\mu(T^{-1}(A))=\mu(A) \hspace{0.2cm} \forall A \in \beta.$

We denote by $\mathcal{M}(X,T)$ the set of $T-$invariant Borel probability measures.

For $\mu \in \mathcal{M}(X, T),$ the set $G_{\mu}$ of $\mu-$generic points is defined by
$$
G_{\mu}:=\left\{x \in X: \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \delta_{T^{j} x} \rightarrow \mu \text { in the weak }^{*} \text { topology as } n \rightarrow \infty\right\}
$$
where $\delta_{y}$ denotes the probability measure whose support is the single point $y$.

Let $\mu$ be an ergodic measure. By Birkhoff ergodic theorem, $\mu(G_{\mu})=1$.

$\textit{Question:}$ Let $\mu$ be an ergodic measure and $x$ be a $\mu-$generic point.  Why is $\mu(B(x, \frac{1}{h}))>0$ for every $h \in \mathbb{N}$, where $B(x, \frac{1}{h})$ is the ball of radius $\frac{1}{h}$ centered at $x.$?

I think one should consider $\chi_{B(x, 1/h)}$ in Birkhoff ergodic theorem, but I don't know how to get the sum is positive.

Answer (score 3):

This claim seems false to me. Consider $X=\{0,1\}$ with $T(0)=T(1)=1$. Then $0$ is a generic point for the measure $\delta_1$, but is not contained in the support of the measure.

Comment: What is $T$? do you consider a full shift?

Comment: The claim is false.  Another such example is $X = [0,1]$ and $Tx:=x^2$, with $\mu=\delta_0$.  Then every $x\in [0,1)$ is generic for $\mu$, but $x = 1/2$ is not in the support of $\mu$.